# std::system_error after restoring model in Tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to implement a simple saver/restorer like so: ([copied from Tensorflow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model))

### Saver:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Create some variables.
v1 = tf.get_variable("v1", shape=[3], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer)
v2 = tf.get_variable("v2", shape=[5], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer)

inc_v1 = v1.assign(v1+1)
dec_v2 = v2.assign(v2-1)

# Add an op to initialize the variables.
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Add ops to save and restore all the variables.
saver = tf.train.Saver()

# Later, launch the model, initialize the variables, do some work, and save the
# variables to disk.
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init_op)
  # Do some work with the model.
  inc_v1.op.run()
  dec_v2.op.run()
  # Save the variables to disk.
  save_path = saver.save(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
  print("Model saved in file: %s" % save_path)
```

### Restorer:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.reset_default_graph()

# Create some variables.
v1 = tf.get_variable("v1", shape=[3])
v2 = tf.get_variable("v2", shape=[5])

# Add ops to save and restore all the variables.
saver = tf.train.Saver()

# Later, launch the model, use the saver to restore variables from disk, and
# do some work with the model.
with tf.Session() as sess:
  # Restore variables from disk.
  saver.restore(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
  print("Model restored.")
  # Check the values of the variables
  print("v1 : %s" % v1.eval())
  print("v2 : %s" % v2.eval())
```

It seems to save the model fine, but when restoring it gets stuck on the line `saver.restore(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")` and I end up with the error message:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
what(): Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I don't see how it can be a memory error as I am running on my work server which has 100s of GB of memory.

Python Version 3.5, Tensorflow version 1.2.1

Comment: Excuse me, how did you conclude that it's a memory error? The quoted exception message tells just about some "Resource".

Comment: I didn't conclude it is a memory error, I was just adding information about my memory situation in case that was a possibility

Comment: your code is working fine; it might be your machine related issue, not a tensroflow issue.

Comment: I guessed as much. Do you have any suggestions on what the error actually means so I can target my troubleshooting better?

Comment: Did you figure this one out? I am having the same problem. Are you on Ubuntu or some other OS? (There's a Github issue suggesting the OS might be the issue.)

Comment: Any insight on this one?
I'm having the same issue
thanks